# Holding a reference to a unique_ptr while looping

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I want to hold a reference to a unique_ptr while using a loop, so that after I get out of the loop I still hold the reference. I know that I can't create a new copy of the unique_ptr (obviously), so what I want to do is something like:

```
const unique_ptr<Object>& ref;
for(auto& s : stuff) {
    if(condition) {
         ref = std::move(s);
    }
}
```

I realize this will never work because ref must be initialized at declaration if it is to be a const, but in that same motion I can't hold a reference to a unique_ptr unless it is a const unique_ptr& type if I am not mistaken.
What I ended up doing is:

```
Object* ref = nullptr;
for(auto& s : stuff) {
    if(condition) {
         ref = s.get();
    }
}
```

Is that a correct solution or should I just consider using shared_ptr for this job?

Comment: Did you mean `Object* ref`?

Comment: @Mohit, yes, I'll edit the post

Comment: Note that the functional solutions below have an implicit `return` after the first successful find. You will need to edit them if that isn't OK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't do any of that! You shouldn't even use a loop [explicitly]! Instead, just find the position and go from there:

```
auto it = std::find_if(stuff.begin, stuff.end(),
     [](std::unique_ptr<Object> const& s){ return condition(s); });
if (it != stuff.end()) {
    // get your unique_ptr as appropriate from *it
}
else {
    // deal with the fact that nothing was found
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Functional style to the rescue!

```
const auto &ref = *std::find_if(stuff.begin(), stuff.end(), [=](const std::unique_ptr<Object> &p) {
    return <condition>;
});
```

Alternatively, move assignment:

```
std::unique_ptr<Object> ref;
for (auto &&s : stuff) {
    if (condition) {
        ref = std::move(s);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if `std::find_if` doesn't find anything? Dereferencing the result that is downright dangerous.

Comment: @ildjarn Of course, in real life, one checks if `find_if` returns `stuff.end()`. I assumed that OP knows that error checking must be done, and I left it out for clarity's sake. Of course, dereferencing the past-end iterator is undefined behavior.

Comment: I meant to imply, if you're going to post example code, you should make it exemplary. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn Ah, I see. You're right that it's a good idea to teach pieces of good practice in public answers.

Answer (score 0):

I know this may seem counter-intuitive but, given that your object is already managed by a `std::unique_ptr`, and therefore its *destruction* is *guaranteed*, I see nothing wrong with using the raw pointer:

```
Object* o = nullptr;

for(auto& s : stuff) {
    if(condition) {
         o = s.get();
    }
}

if(o) {
    // use o->stuff() here
}
```